# DateTime format reference & determine days to months

Tags: php, date, datetime

I used `DateTime` to get the diff of two dates. Directly from the PHP documentation example:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2012/03/15');
$date2 = new DateTime('2012/6/9');
$interval = $date1->diff($date2,true);
$days = $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

This will result in **`+86 days`**, I wonder where can I get the reference for those `%R%a` I don't know what they mean, but I just know by seeing that `%R = +` while `%a is number of days`.

Second, now by having the value **`86`** I can have at least a variable that I can use to tell that `$date1` and `$date2` is not within the length of 3 months (3 months is at least 90 days). I can simply use an `if-else` for this, however for precision, is there another way (built-in PHP functions or library) to determine that the value I have is within the period of 3 months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check the documentation for [`DateTime::diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).
2. See that it returns a `DateInterval`, click link to [its documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php).
3. Read [documentation for its `format` method](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php).

Use `if ($interval->format('%m') > 3)` to test if it's over three months. Notice that this is only the months portion of the interval, e.g. "3" of "2 years, 3 months". Take the years into account as well. You should not just use days for this, since there's no constant number of days in a month. 90 days and 3 months are not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for this buddy. I'm still having a hard time digging the PHP documentation. Thanks for the explanation as well, it enlightens me.

Comment: +1 for highlighting the years and months that'd I hadn't mentioned in my response

Comment: @fish Get used to it, it's the single best source of information for PHP. It's pretty simple too, once you learn to read it. Functions have parameters and a return value, interspersed with those you'll find explanations and examples and links to other related functions. All those are very useful. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can find it [in the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) as well:

```
%   Literal %   %
Y   Years, numeric, at least 2 digits with leading 0    01, 03
y   Years, numeric  1, 3
M   Months, numeric, at least 2 digits with leading 0   01, 03, 12
m   Months, numeric 1, 3, 12
D   Days, numeric, at least 2 digits with leading 0 01, 03, 31
d   Days, numeric   1, 3, 31
a   Total number of days as a result of a DateTime:diff() or (unknown) otherwise    4, 18, 8123
H   Hours, numeric, at least 2 digits with leading 0    01, 03, 23
h   Hours, numeric  1, 3, 23
I   Minutes, numeric, at least 2 digits with leading 0  01, 03, 59
i   Minutes, numeric    1, 3, 59
S   Seconds, numeric, at least 2 digits with leading 0  01, 03, 57
s   Seconds, numeric    1, 3, 57
R   Sign "-" when negative, "+" when positive   -, +
r   Sign "-" when negative, empty when positive -,
```

Comment: Great find, I cannot see nor landed in this page.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php for the docs

```
$months = 3;
if ($interval->format('%m') < $months) {
   echo "Less than $months months";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this buddy. I get the thought from your answer.